# I cannot use the bash command "clear" in my terminal

Tags: bash, installer-anaconda, datascience-anaconda

I started cleaning out files from my home directory. I recall deleting two files "bash" and "anaconda3" which may be contributing to my problem.

In any case, I attempted to use the "clear" command to empty my terminal as I have done hundreds of times, but was met with the following output:

"bash: /home/alexandre/anaconda3/bin/clear: No such file or directory"

If I recall, I downloaded anaconda3 while working with a colleague's command line tool, but I certainly haven't gotten much use out of it since then and I am certain I was able to use the command prior to downloading anaconda3.

I can't seem to recall where to download the specific file, but I am skeptical of whether I need it to work around this issue to begin with.

Comment: run `hash -r`, then try `clear` again.

Comment: If the above does not work, try `/usr/bin/clear` and/or open a new terminal and just type `clear`.

Comment: what is the output of `whereis bash`?

Comment: type `type clear`

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/122911